# Eclipse JSDT stops giving proposals when using @memberOf

Tags: javascript, eclipse, jsdoc, code-hinting, jsdt

since i like to code in javascript pretty much like in other OOP environments, i like to modularize my code, like, creating a top namespace for my JS application like this:

```
var myapp = {};
myapp.module = {
 member_function: function(param) {
 ...
 },...
};
```

this makes my code layout pretty easy to follow, and since these are not plugins and not "classes" to be instantiated, this format is plain and simple.

however, since eclipse's jsdt outline generator only goes one level deep by default, the outline only shows the top modules and does not go into revealing the member functions, properties etc. i understand this is to protect from circular references etc, but is not too helpful during development.

i actually actively create jsdoc snippets for my code, even if eclipse does not use it per se and does not show online docs or offer hints based on @returns types. i just keep adding docs to help me remember what does what, what are the parameters for etc. :) and of course, hoping that maybe one day eclipse jsdt will make use of these things.

now, however, i just found out about the fantastic @memberOf thing. all of a sudden, my modules are explorable in the outline view. yippe... ee...

all of a sudden as well, code proposals stop working on the module. proposals go as long as myapp. , which would show .module, but after myapp.module., no proposals are given. if i delete @memberOf, code proposals work again for the module, but the module is no longer explorable in outline.

anyone knows of a way where both outline explorer and code proposals work in jsdt? (and don't say netbeans, which is fabulous for js and html, but very skippy for php, no yaml support, etc. i need my eclipse, alas.)

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer, I'm the author of [tern.java](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java).

I suggest you that you [install tern.java 1.2.0-SNAPSHOT](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Installation-Update-Site) and you will benefit with tern outline and JS completion:

[image]